# View.invalidate() is extremely slow. Alternatives?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-ndk

I'm doing some bitmap animation in native code, so I need to redraw the ImageView every frame:

```
class MyImageView extends ImageView
{
    ...

    protected void onDraw( Canvas canvas )
    {
        native_drawStuff( handle, canvas );
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Seems all well and good, except that Traceview shows this:

[image]

I don't know about you, but that seems kind of absurd. native_drawStuff() is setting every pixel of a bitmap then drawing the bitmap to the canvas, and a simple invalidate() call takes almost **4 times longer** than that? The bitmaps aren't small either (RGBA_8888 and anywhere from 50k to 300k pixels).

Given my need to redraw the entire ImageView every frame, is there a better way to do this? The only advice on this that I've seen is to only invalidate the part of the view that you need to redraw, but in my case that's the entire thing anyway.

Comment: Why are you invalidating in onDraw()?  It suggests that you might not understand how invalidate works?

Comment: I'm invalidating from onDraw() because logically it should achieve the maximum refresh rate for my animation. The docs say this about invalidate(): "If the view is visible, onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called at some point in the future" which is exactly the behavior that I want. Without constantly invalidating, the animation is not updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API 14 introduced the perfect class for this: [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html)

> A TextureView can be used to display a content stream. Such a content
>   stream can for instance be a video or an OpenGL scene. The content
>   stream can come from the application's process as well as a remote
>   process.

Romain Guy posted an example of how to stream content to the TextureView from another Thread here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/_Ogjc8sozpA. I'm copying it here for posterity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

@SuppressWarnings({"UnusedDeclaration"})
public class CanvasTextureViewActivity extends Activity
        implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {
    private TextureView mTextureView;
    private CanvasTextureViewActivity.RenderingThread mThread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FrameLayout content = new FrameLayout(this);

        mTextureView = new TextureView(this);
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
        mTextureView.setOpaque(false);

        content.addView(mTextureView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(500, 500, Gravity.CENTER));
        setContentView(content);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        mThread = new RenderingThread(mTextureView);
        mThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        // Ignored
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        if (mThread != null) mThread.stopRendering();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        // Ignored
    }

    private static class RenderingThread extends Thread {
        private final TextureView mSurface;
        private volatile boolean mRunning = true;

        public RenderingThread(TextureView surface) {
            mSurface = surface;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            float x = 0.0f;
            float y = 0.0f;
            float speedX = 5.0f;
            float speedY = 3.0f;

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(0xff00ff00);

            while (mRunning && !Thread.interrupted()) {
                final Canvas canvas = mSurface.lockCanvas(null);
                try {
                    canvas.drawColor(0x00000000, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                    canvas.drawRect(x, y, x + 20.0f, y + 20.0f, paint);
                } finally {
                    mSurface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }

                if (x + 20.0f + speedX >= mSurface.getWidth() || x + speedX <= 0.0f) {
                    speedX = -speedX;
                }
                if (y + 20.0f + speedY >= mSurface.getHeight() || y + speedY <= 0.0f) {
                    speedY = -speedY;
                }

                x += speedX;
                y += speedY;

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(15);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // Interrupted
                }
            }
        }

        void stopRendering() {
            interrupt();
            mRunning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When the RenderingThread does a lot of drawing, it can still be doing drawing operations after the TextureView is destroyed. This can cause a segmentation fault and crash the app. The way I solved the problem was by mThread.Join() in the onSurfaceTextureDestroyed method. This blocks the destruction of the TexureView until the frame drawing is complete.

Answer (score -1):

You should'nt call invalidate() in onDraw, since invalidate() calls onDraw() ASAP on the UI thread. You should use postInvalidateDelayed(delayMilliseconds); (not intentionally in onDraw()) if you want to refresh the view at intervals, or use different Thread or Handler.
If you are trying to refresh the view frequently, use:

```
 YourView v;

 //starting refreshing view , prefer to start it in onresume
 Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable(){
      @Override
      public void run(){
           v.invalidate();
           v.postDelayed(updateRunnable, 1000 / 30);//1000 ms / 30fps
      }
 };
 v.post(updateRunnable);
 ...
 //stopping it
 v.removeCallbacks(updateRunnable);//prefer to do it in onpause
```

this will update your view with 30fps. If your performance can handle it.

Comment: "invalidate() calls onDraw() ASAP" is exactly what I want! invalidate() certainly doesn't directly call onDraw() or I would be getting stack overflows. Regardless I will try moving the invalidate call outside of onDraw(), however the docs make no mention of such a restriction: "If the view is visible, onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called at some point in the future".

Comment: I moved the invalidating into a TimerTask, but it didn't make any measurable difference. It seems like invalidate() is slow no matter where you call it from.