# Changing Android icon color with setColorFilter() usually works, but not always

Tags: android, android-view, android-drawable, android-icons, porter-duff

#### Scenario

In testing, and in most cases, the app responds  to `setColorFilter` as expected (the icon changes color).  I've recently had a report that a user with Samsung S22+ is NOT seeing the icons change color.

#### Relevant Code

I've pulled out what I thought to be code that is applicable from the overall application.

```
int colorIconActive = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorIconActiveDark); //<color name="colorIconActiveDark">#3199BB</color>
int colorIconNonActive = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorIconNonActiveDark); //<color name="colorIconNonActiveDark">#444444</color>

Drawable tapIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.tap); // tap.png
View tapIcon = findViewById(R.id.tap_icon); 
/*
       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tap_icon"
            android:onClick="onClickUpdateIcons"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/tap"
            android:contentDescription="draught beer"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            />
*/

if (condition) {
    tapIcon.setColorFilter(colorIconNonActive, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
else {
    tapIcon.setColorFilter(colorIconActive, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
}

tapIcon.invalidate();
```

This code has been working on all devices, as far as I know, for years.  I just got a report today that indicates the icon colors are not changing.  The underlying function of touching the icon DOES work for this user, but the icons are reported to not be changing color.

- compileSdkVersion 30
- targetSdkVersion 30
- minSdkVersion 14

#### Question

Are there any known problems when using the icon color change technique that's being employed above?  If so, do those problems have work-arounds? I wrote this a long time ago, and so don't know what's going on with `invalidate()`, but it's been working up until now.  Is there a more reliable way to change icon color, hopefully while not abandoning people who are limping along with an old phone?

Comment: Please try this filter `setColorFilter(BlendModeColorFilterCompat.createBlendModeColorFilterCompat(color, BlendModeCompat.SRC_ATOP))`

Comment: @Zain This required updating my `import: androidx.core` version and SDK to 32.  It compiles, but don't know if it works yet. Thanks.

Comment: @Zain The user reports the same thing: the icon colors change at first, but later are not changing.

Answer (score 2):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711547/view-invalidate-is-extremely-slow-alternatives) mentioning issues with `view.invalidate` (slowness, not lack of response) mentions that you could use a `TextureView`.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794434/android-textureview-set-background-color-and-show-video-later) notes you can change the color by placing the `TextureView` in its own layout and then change the background color.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52045122/10981777) to a similar question notes that you may need to post the change to the views message queue on later APIs (21+).  Notably, the general approach of `setColorFilter(Color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)` seems to be preferred by a lot of app makers.  Answers related to older Samsung hardware in the same thread also note "applying it in the `draw(Canvas canvas)` method" or using `DrawCompat` with `setTint` and `setTintMode`.

Finally, because its only the S22+, it may also be a specific issue with the phone.  There have been a lot of complaints about video and image rendering on the S22+ and a hidden [game optimizing service](http://www.businesskorea.co.kr/news/articleView.html?idxno=88602) that cause stutter, lag, and [graphical draw bugs](https://piunikaweb.com/2022/10/25/galaxy-s22-ultra-camera-shutter-lag-performance-issues-surface/).  Samsung is apparently also having issues pushing updates correctly.